# VBA Form doesn't shows second time

Tags: vba, userform

I've got a problem with my VBA Login Form which should protect my book.
I've created LoginPage and 2 login forms: for a student and for a teacher. They are similar in use, but does not work correctly.

If I chose "Log as a Teacher" button but then decided to close this window for logging by a student, QueryClose method should work. But this works once. 
And in the LoginPage when I press CommandButton TeacherForm shows only once too. So as you have already understood I need to switch easily between these forms.

My code(LoginPage) is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
Cancel = True
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TeacherLogin_Click()
Unload Me
Load TeacherForm
TeacherForm.Show
End Sub
```

TeacherForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = 0 Then
    Cancel = True
    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
    Load LoginPage
    LoginPage.Show
End If
End Sub
Private Sub PTTB_Change()
PTTB.PasswordChar = "*"
End Sub
Private Sub SubmitTeacher_Click()
If LTTB.Value = "User" Then
    If PTTB.Value = "SuperUser" Then
        MsgBox ("Access granted!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Access denied!")
    End If
Else
    MsgBox ("Access denied!")
End If
End Sub
```

Help me if I do something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are unloading the Form's Default Instance.  You should be instantiating new instances of the Userforms and hiding them instead of unloading them.  This article explains it best [Rubberduck VBA: UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TeacherLogin_Click()
    Dim Form As TeacherForm
    Set Form = New TeacherForm
    Form.Show
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
        Dim Form As LoginPage
        Set Form = New LoginPage
        Form.Show
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PTTB_Change()
    PTTB.PasswordChar = "*"
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitTeacher_Click()
    If LTTB.Value = "User" Then
        If PTTB.Value = "SuperUser" Then
            MsgBox ("Access granted!")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Access denied!")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Access denied!")
    End If
End Sub
```

You should consider downloading [Rubberduck VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/), its Free The code formatting feature will save you a ton of time.

Comment: And it's done! After MsgBox I've added one more Unload and now i'm working on my MainPage. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

@TinMan is correct -- you should absolutely create new instances of your UserForms and work directly with those.

***Furthermore***, I wouldn't advise showing the next form from the `UserForm_QueryClose` event.

When working with multiple UserForms it can be useful to have a "presenter" class to hold the instances and control the showing/ hiding of the different forms. 
Here's a simple example, which is similar to your requirements:

---

Create a simple UserForm (**UserForm1**) with the following code and one button named "ShowUF2" which will open the second UserForm. This is your main form.

```
Public Event ShowUF2ButtonClicked()

Private Sub ShowUF2_Click()
    RaiseEvent ShowUF2ButtonClicked
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Create another UserForm (**UserForm2**) with just the QueryClose code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Now create your presenter Class (**Presenter**) to hold instances and control the showing & hiding

```
Private WithEvents UF1 As UserForm1
Private UF2 As UserForm2

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set UF1 = New UserForm1
End Sub

Public Sub Present()
    UF1.Show vbModal
End Sub

Private Sub UF1_ShowUF2ButtonClicked()
    UF1.Hide
    Set UF2 = New UserForm2
    UF2.Show vbModal
    UF1.Show vbModal 'when UF2 is closed, show UF1 again
End Sub
```

Then, finally, you just need to create a presenter and hit the "Present" sub. This needs to be in a standard module

```
Public Sub ShowUF1()
    With New Presenter
        .Present
    End With
End Sub
```